# Connection to internet successful, however no browsers will load pages

Tags: internet

Recently, my ubuntu suddenly stopped loading webpages. I am getting the `page not found` or `server not found` error. This happens on multiple browsers. I have fine connection to either WiFi or ethernet, I also run Windows on the same machine and this has no issues with the internet. There is nothing I have changed that I can think of.

Typing in terminal: `host google.com` gives the response: `connection timed out; no servers could be reached.`

typing `ping -c 5 google.com` only gives the response: `Ping: unknown host google.com.`

I have gone through and checked all the network settings I can think of, and as I said I have full network connectivity, just no pages will load at all. If there is anyone that can help I would be most grateful.

Comment: Please add the output of `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8` to your question. This helps to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Can you tell us the make and model of your computer and WiFi adapter?

Comment: You need a "default route". Inspect your routes with `ip route`, and read `man ip;man ip-route` to see how to set upo a "default route".

Comment: It sounds like your DNS servers aren't responding. Did you make any changes in your DNS servers recently? DNS servers allow the user to specify www.whatever.com instead of unwieldy IP addresses like 8.8.8.8.